# How to append result of for loop in excel file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .txt file with a list of keywords, I read this file and for each keyword generate some kind of string. I would like to append this string generated for each keyword to excel file. I'd like also that each time I re run the script and read .txt file with new keywords, result is always appended to the same excel file instead of overwriting it.

I have tried this, but not sure if `openpyxl` is a good method, also I get an error:

> raise ValueError("{0} is not a valid column name".format(str_col))
>   ValueError: tapis roulant elettrico  is not a valid column name
>   for line 
>   page.append(some_result)

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

headers = ['data']
workbook_name = 'Example.xlsx'
wb = Workbook()
page = wb.active
page.title = 'data'

page.append(headers)
some_result = {}
val = "some result"

with open("keywords.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        some_result = {line: val}
        page.append(some_result)
        wb.save(filename=workbook_name)
file.close()
```

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative method to `openpyxl`, or is there an issue with your above implementation?

Comment: I have an issue with page.append(some_result),   raise ValueError("{0} is not a valid column name".format(str_col))
ValueError: keyword1
 is not a valid column name

Comment: From your error, It looks like while appending, you are trying to append the value to column name That doesn't exist. So you have to check if the column exists or not. If it doesn't then create one else append

Comment: it's strange since I have just one column with header "data" and all "some_result" values should be appended to that column, each result on a new row of the same column

Answer (score 0):

Just my opinion, its definitely not a good idea to save your file for every entry in your loop. Itll slow things down and overall it will probably break things and make them more complicated. I think it is likely you are saving a new column name on every iteration. I made a few changes/comments that I didnt really test, but hopefully it might help you get moving in the right direction. I'm assuming you just want a single column in your excel sheet with the keywords you mention, but to give you a complete solution I would need to know details about whether youre allowing duplicates, why you need it in excel format at all, and a few other things. If a CSV is acceptable (excel can read these) then there is a much simpler solution than what youre doing if you use numpy and or pandas.

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

headers = ['data']
workbook_name = 'Example.xlsx'
wb = Workbook()
page = wb.active
page.title = 'data'

page.append(headers)
some_result = {}
val = "some result"
temp_page_list = []

with open("keywords.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        some_result = {line: val}
        #print(some_result)
        #dont append to your real excel file here in the loop, doing it in a simple list will be less complicated and faster
        #page.append(some_result)
        temp_page_list.append(some_result)
        #dont save things here
        #wb.save(filename=workbook_name)

file.close()


#print some or all of temp_page_list here
#if it looks right, you can perhaps convert the list directly by iterating and saving the elements
#a better option may be to use a built in function from openpyxl to add the contents of temp_page_list if such a function exists
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ishiffman, .csv is totally acceptable. The thing is, have used a simplified example, in a real code for each keyword (there might be some 1000 keywords) I get some_result in JSON format, if I will append each some_result value to a temp_page_list and then create a .csv with pandas, would not it create an issue due to a temp_page_list ?

Comment: Ok so youre iterating over the lines that may have numerous keywords. Im going to assume a couple things and give you a flow that would be how I would write it.:

-create set before opening file
-begin loop which reads keywords from file
-read in line from file
-split string that was read in based on " ", add results of split to temporary list
-add temporary list items to your set (which is unique)
-end loop

-convert set to numpy array or pandas dataframe, this can be done using built in functions
-save numpy array or dataframe as csv

Answer (score -1):

I have not worked with openpyxl before but I want to give you a general understanding of the python code that you wrote.

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

headers = ['data']
workbook_name = 'Example.xlsx'
wb = Workbook()
page = wb.active
page.title = 'data'

page.append(headers)
some_result = {}
val = "some result"

with open("keywords.txt", "r") as file:
for line in file:
    # some_result = {line: val} # this is a dictionary
    some_result = val + str(line) # this is a string
    page.append(some_result)
    wb.save(filename=workbook_name)
file.close()
```

You are trying to append a dictionary with `Key` being the line variable and the `Value` associated with this key is the some_result variable. While you are trying to append this `Key, Value Pair`, I think it is assuming that you want to append the Value in a row that is associated with the Key as the column (but the Key doesn't exist already). So if you try the above code, I think it would append everything under one column. If you want separate column then you need to create columns if they don't exist

Comment: According to the docu [`Worksheet.append`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=worksheet%20append#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.append)  expects a `iterable` and not a `str`. Also `wb.save(...` have to be done **once** not at every line of data.

Comment: Thanks, @uttejh All this dictionary is just an example, I actually use an API  in a real code that generates a certain result for each keyword then I was searching to append it all in one column in excel